# How do I get my text do display longer when I click on the button to copy text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it so that when I click on the text, which is a button, it displays the 'copied' text longer than the duration that I am clicking the button. I am having no issue for the text to display when I want, I just need the 'copied' message to display longer.

```
.hexcodeStyle {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  border: white solid 0;
}


.hexcodeStyle:before {
  --scale: 0;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  top: -.25rem;
  left: 50%;
  padding: .3rem;
  width: max-content;
  background: lightgray;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-100%) scale(var(--scale));
  border-radius: .3rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: 100ms;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

.hexcodeStyle:hover::before{
  --scale: 1;
  content: 'Copy color';
  
}

.hexcodeStyle:active::before{
  
  content: 'Copied!';
  
}

<script>
function copyHex(celement) { 
    let hexCopy = celement.innerText;
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('value', hexCopy);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();

    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(input);

}



$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hexcodeStyle').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(':active::before').removeClass('active');
        },2000);          
    });        
});
</script>
```

I tried to add transition to active but this does not work

Comment: `:active !== .active` there's no styles for the class `active`.

Comment: Use `mousedown` listener event to add the class, and then listen for `mouseup` event to add the timeout to remove the class after your desired time